# "init: Failed to spawn google main process: unable to execute: No such file or directory" in /var/log/syslog

Tags: google-compute-engine

When booting up or restarting one of my instances in Google Compute Engine, I'm getting this error in /var/log/syslog.

Without the "google" service/process, I'm unable (among other things) to update my SSH keys from GCE's Metadata.

Running

```
  sudo service google start
```

gives me the error

```
  start: Job failed to start
```

with the same error line in /var/log/syslog.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed myself by following the "From Source Repository" installation instructions in this git repo: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages

It appears that all the /usr/... and /etc/... files were missing.